# Elasticsearch AccessDeniedException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes] on ECS Fargate

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am deploying elasticserch 7.16.1 on ECS Fargate using bind mount. The container terminates with following error.

```
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[failed to bind service]; nested: AccessDeniedException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes];
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:157) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]
at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:77) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:112) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:77) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:122) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to bind service
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:1090) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:309) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:234) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:234) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:434) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:166) ~[elasticsearch-7.16.1.jar:7.16.1]
```

Looks like the container does not have write permission on the volume, but the volume is not read-only. The task-definition is as below.

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/elasticsearch-dev",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 9200,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 9200
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "discovery.type",
          "value": "single-node"
        },
        {
          "name": "ES_JAVA_OPTS",
          "value": "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
        }
      ],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": [
        {
          "name": "nofile",
          "softLimit": 65536,
          "hardLimit": 65536
        }
      ],
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "readOnly": null,
          "containerPath": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data",
          "sourceVolume": "host-data"
        }
      ],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.1",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "elasticsearch-dev"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "8192",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:task-definition/elasticsearch-dev:7",
  "family": "elasticsearch-dev",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "runtimePlatform": null,
  "cpu": "1024",
  "revision": 7,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "fsxWindowsFileServerVolumeConfiguration": null,
      "efsVolumeConfiguration": null,
      "name": "host-data",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": null
      },
      "dockerVolumeConfiguration": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

elasticsearch:7.13.0 has [added a `USER` directive](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v7.13.0/distribution/docker/src/docker/Dockerfile#L201) in the Dockerfile that ensures elasticsearch container to be run by elasticsearch user instead of root user. But AWS ECS still [mounts volume owned by root user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bind-mounts.html#bind-mount-considerations), that's why elasticsearch user can't write to it raising AccessDeniedException.

ECS docs [suggests to add a `VOLUME` directive](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bind-mounts.html#bind-mount-considerations) after `USER` directive in the Dockerfile to make the volume owned by the non-root user. I ended up with the following Dockerfile to build elasticsearch image myself and push it to ECR to make it work.

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.1

VOLUME ["/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
```